# Loading the data from file in to Maria DB table,issues while loading

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

I am identifying the file in a folder and pick the file and read the file using BufferedReader and read line by line and **convert that line into ArrayList object**(this is taking lot of time,since it has fifty columns) and prepares a preparedstatement and add it to the batch,once i add 4000 records to the batch,we commit the data to the table.all this process is taking time,since it is a read from the file and insert it into table,i followed the following approach:
1)Iterate over each line int the file and put each line as an String object in the List(assume the size of the list is 93000).
2)break the list into sublists(each sublist size is 4000.),that means we get 24 sublists.
3)i have created Threads using Callable Interface along with Executor Framework.
4)i pass each sublist to one thread,that means in my case it is 24 threads.
5) each thread converts the each String object in the sublist to prepared statement and add it to the batch and commit once 4000k records are added.

problem is:

while loading the file,sometimes,some records are not loaded and some times records are correctly loaded into the table.
->when i am running it multiple time,sometimes only 5 records will be missed,some times 1000,sometimes 3230 records,sometime 100% loaded correctly.
->can someone please help me to understand,why is is showing this behavior.

Comment: *1)read the complete file* - bad start

Answer (score 0):

1. `CREATE` a table that mirrors the structure of the file.
2. Use `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` to read the file and populate that table.
3. Use queries to massage the data.
4. Look at the data to see if it look "correct".
5. Copy the data to the desired target(s).
6. `DROP` the table used here.

No loops, no batching, no file reading, no Arrays, no iterating.
All SQL.